# Reload page after locale change

Tags: flutter, dart, localization

After changing locale in `context.setLocale()` language in inactive widgets change. But I cannot figure out, hoe to reload current widget in new locale. Any ideas how to get it working?

Body of widget:

```dart
Form(
  child: CardSettings(
    children: <CardSettingsSection>[
      CardSettingsSection(
        header: CardSettingsHeader(
          label: 'settings.general'.tr(),
        ),
        children: [
          CardSettingsListPicker(
            label: 'Language',
            items: context.supportedLocales
                .map((locale) =>
                    locale.toStringWithSeparator(separator: ' '))
                .toList(),
            initialItem:
                context.locale.toStringWithSeparator(separator: ' '),
            onChanged: (String newLocale) {
              context.setLocale(newLocale.toLocale(separator: ' '));
              _getOptions();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      CardSettingsSection(
        header: CardSettingsHeader(
          label: 'Map',
        ),
        children: [
          CardSettingsListPicker(
            label: 'default floor',
            items: _floorList,
            initialItem: _floor,
            onChanged: (String value) {
              var floor = tr('plan.floor.' + value);
              _preferences.setString('mapDefaultFloor', floor);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

And options are loaded via async function called in initState and later on in code...

```dart
void _getOptions() {
  setState(() {
    _floorList = Floor.values
        .map((value) => tr('plan.floor.' + value.toString().split('.')[1]))
        .toList();
    _planTypeList = PlanType.values
        .map((value) => tr('plan.type.' + value.toString().split('.')[1]))
        .toList();
    _floor = tr('plan.floor.' +
        (_preferences.getString('mapDefaultFLoor') ?? 'ground'));
    _planType = tr('plan.type.' +
        (_preferences.getString('mapDefaultType') ?? 'newNumbers'));
  });
}
```

Comment: use setState to update/reload your current screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was to make `_getOptions()` async and add the locale change there with await keyword. This way it is ensured that locale is changed before loading new values...

Answer (score 0):

stateful widgets automatically reload when you update their state. therefore, all you need to do is have your widget set as a StatefulWidget, and use the `setState` function to tell flutter that a change has been made to the state, and the widget needs to reload.

**Taken from the flutter project template:**

```
setState(() {
  // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
  // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
  // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
  // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
  // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
  _counter++;
});
```

in the example showed above, the `_counter` is updated in the state, and in order for it to show the correct value on the app itself, the `setState` function is called.

Comment: Hi, I'm updating the lists with `setState` basically the whole `_getOptions` is basically just reusable setState call... But it does not rerender the widget with new data. That is what I am confused about... (I use this approach in other parts of app where I change for example pictures etc. And everything works...)